# How to fill multiple spinners with unique values ? and handling on its item selected listener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I wanted to fill data inside multiple spinners with no repeated data into it

I have tried and filled the three spinners but still m not able to select the data properly so please help me providing some example

my scenario :
When i select any item from 1 st spinner then that item should not be repeated in 2nd and 3rd spinner and same vice-versa for other two spinners

my code :

```
private Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;
    ArrayList<String> MAinArrayList;
    ArrayList<String> TempList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.final_sp);

        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        TempList = new ArrayList<String>();
        MAinArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        MAinArrayList.add("a");
        MAinArrayList.add("b");
        MAinArrayList.add("c");
        MAinArrayList.add("d");
        MAinArrayList.add("e");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MAinArrayList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        sp1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        final String strA = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        TempList.addAll(MAinArrayList);
        for (int i = 0; i < TempList.size(); i++) {
            if (TempList.get(i).equals(strA)) {
                TempList.remove(strA);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < TempList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Templist " + (i) + "==>" + TempList.get(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempList);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        sp2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
//        ArrayList<String> TempList1 = new ArrayList<>();
//        TempList1.addAll(MAinArrayList);

//        if (TempList.size() > 0) {
//            TempList.clear();
//        }
        //TempList.addAll(MAinArrayList);

        final String strB = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final ArrayList<String> TempList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        TempList1.addAll(TempList);
        System.out.println("Templist1 ADDDED" + TempList1);

        for (int i = 0; i < TempList1.size(); i++) {
            if (TempList1.get(i).equals(strB)) {
                TempList1.remove(strB);
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("removed templist " + TempList1);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < TempList1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("TempList3 " + (i) + "==>" + TempList1.get(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempList1);
        dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        sp3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);

        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayList<String> TempSP2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                TempSP2.addAll(MAinArrayList);
                System.out.println("TempSP2 ==>" + TempSP2);
                String strC = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String strA = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP2.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP2.get(i).equals(strC)) {
                        TempSP2.remove(strC);
                        break ;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP2.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP2.get(i).equals(strA)) {
                        TempSP2.remove(strA);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("removed TempSP2 strAC" + TempSP2);

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerDemo.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempSP2);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                sp2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayList<String> TempSP3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                TempSP3.addAll(MAinArrayList);
                System.out.println("TempSP3 ==>" + TempSP3);
                String strA = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String strB = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP3.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP3.get(i).equals(strA)) {
                        TempSP3.remove(strA);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP3.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP3.get(i).equals(strB)) {
                        TempSP3.remove(strB);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("removed TempSP3 strAb" + TempSP3);

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerDemo.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempSP3);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                sp3.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayList<String> TempSP1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                TempSP1.addAll(MAinArrayList);
                System.out.println("TempSP1 ==>" + TempSP1);
                String strB = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String strC = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP1.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP1.get(i).equals(strB)) {
                        TempSP1.remove(strB);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < TempSP1.size(); i++) {
                    if (TempSP1.get(i).equals(strC)) {
                        TempSP1.remove(strC);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("removed TempSP1 strBC" + TempSP1);

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerDemo.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TempSP1);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                sp1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific? Put the code you've tried

Comment: @Shailee please post your code what you have tried?

Comment: google it first.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716251/how-to-implements-multiple-spinner-with-different-item-list-and-different-action

Comment: ok  i am editin n sending my code

Comment: @brahmyadigopula thanks but am not able to set data on selection of an item above given code of mine is not allowing me to select any item from spinner and loop goes in infinite mode

Comment: put spinner onItemSelectedListener and do code inside. @Shailee

Comment: @Shailee, You are adding same data in TempList from MAinArrayList, **TempList.addAll(MAinArrayList);** then you are getting same & repeated data. What you want exactly...

Comment: @Shailee you trying to get the spinner string  from other spinner...spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener() is specific to that particular spinner only..you can't get the other spinner non selected items  sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
sp1.getSelectedItem().toString(); into current selection item of spinner.

Comment: yes @PratikDasa actualy i hav put on itemselected listener for geting the unoque data

Comment: @KuldeepKulkarni actually i wanted to keep mainarraylist to be static do i hav took one templist for removing the repeated data..I actualy wanted to fill spinner with unique data but here my loop goin in infinite times in onitem selected listener

Comment: but @brahmyadigopula i had already set adapter for all three spinners so i can get other spinner selected item becuse i need to compar the selected item data of other spinner on basis of that only i can fill spinner with unique values

Comment: where is your listener? paste the code or come here in this chat room...http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124502/android-dev @Shailee

Comment: i have set listenesr for all 3 spinners in code ..please check s1.setonitemselectedlistener , s2.setonitemselected listener and s3.setonitemselectectedlistener and then i hav performed operation to get uniq value but her my loop goes infinitely

Answer (score 0):

In your project string.xml file write the data you want to put in spinner example:

```
<string-array name="cooking_arrays">
    <item>Spoon</item>
    <item>Cup</item>
    <item>1/2 Cup</item>
    <item>3/4 Cup</item>
</string-array>
```

then  in project layout in spinner properties write in entries field 
@array/cooking_arrays

then in your activity

```
 spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
 String quintity= String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
     switch(quintity){

      case "Spoon":
    //what you want to do
    break;
      case "Cup":
    //what you want to do
    break;}
```

Comment: yes thanks but main concern is hoe do i handle for multipl spinners